# Why isn't my Lennox G26Q3/4-100-6 furnace firing up?

Tags: hvac, heating

I replaced the batteries, does not click when it calls for heat in the thermostat.  fan blows but no heat.  I took off inspection door, held the safety switch in, a blue light is blinking constantly, what is the cause of this, possible igniter bad or thermostat bad?

The fan for the combustion chamber is running, while two blue lights blink fast.

Comment: There should be two LEDs, #1 and #2.  We'll have to know what each one is doing, and whether or not they are flashing fast or slow

Comment: the fan for the combustion chamber is running while two blue lights blink fast

Comment: Label the wires attached to the pressure switch, or take a  photo, or something so you remember how it's hooked up. Set you meter to read ohms or continuity. Pull the wires off the pressure switch, and place one probe one each terminal. With the inducer running, you should measure CLOSED, or a small (not infinite) resistance.

Comment: If the pressure switch is not closing, you'll have to try and figure out why.  Check the vent and intake, to make sure they're not blocked. Make sure the condensate line isn't blocked, or backing up.

Comment: I am going from at work PC to a home PC,  this will take a little time to travel to, please send any advice on this problem it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You could easily visually inspect the vent and intake pipes, to make sure they're not blocked, broken, or damaged.

Comment: Any updates on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Lennox G26 diagnostic codes...

[image]